# How to remove original object after rotation in java graphics2D?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

Specifically, I am trying to display only the rotated object. I have a drawn rectangle and I rotate it.

How to I display only the rotated rectangle and dispose of the old one?

***EDITED:***

The following is the code to rotate my rectangle:

```
    private void rotateRectangle(Graphics g, Rectangle rect, Color c){
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            x = rect.x;
            y = rect.y;
            g2d.setColor(c);
            g2d.rotate(Math.PI/6, PANEL_WIDTH/2,PANEL_HEIGHT/2);
            g2d.drawRect(PANEL_WIDTH/2-x/2, PANEL_HEIGHT/2-y/2, x, y);
        }
```

And this is the paintComponent where I call it from:

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {        
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));

            //these are declared before 
            rect.x = x;
            rect.y = y;

            if(rotateClicked){
                rotateRectangle(g2d,rect,squareColor);
                rotateClicked = false;
            }
            drawRectangle(g2d, rect, squareColor);
            getArea(x,y);
    }
```

Comment: Please share the code you used to draw and rotate the object. You need to put effort into your question if you expect the community to make an effort to answer you.

Comment: Take a closer look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing

Comment: @Zoltán I thought this would have a quick solution, that is why I didn't provide the code, anyways i'm editing the post now to include all I have so far

Comment: Sounded like it was an issue with drawing over itself, turns out it's probably a problem with your if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If custom rendering shapes with a Graphics object by overwriting `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, ensure you use `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first line to clear the drawing area

From there draw your Rectangle/rotated Rectangle

Without using `super.paintComponent(g)`, your previous drawings (the unrotated Rectangle) will remain visible

## EDIT

With the update of source code: you are drawing both the new and the old rectangle because your if statement does not have an else clause

Try inserting an else clause so that it will draw one rectangle or the other, currently it maybe draws a rotated rectangle and then draws the unrotated rectangle

```
if(rotateClicked)
{
    rotateRectangle(g2d,rect,squareColor);
    rotateClicked = false;
}
else
    drawRectangle(g2d, rect, squareColor);
```

You may or may not want a `rotateClicked = true` in the else so it will flip back and forth between rotated and unrotated

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the answer. I included the source code to be more specific. I did use the superclass's constructor though

Comment: Ohh WOW, I can' believe I missed that. Thank you!!

Comment: I have a followup question though, what if I wanted to expand the size of the rotated image? What should I do? Should I record the non-rotated rectangle dimensions, expand and then rotate again? Or is there anything else that I might wanna consider?

Comment: It would probably be easiest to supply rotate rectangle with a larger rectangle, as then you can control on a per-rotated basis which ones you wish to be larger

Comment: I want to control the expansion with a JButton. So,after the rotation is displayed, if the user clicks on expand I want to expand the rotated rectangle. Just to be sure, you are saying that I need to put an if statement in the rotateRectangle function and go from there?

Comment: I was thinking something more along the lines of calling `rotateRectangle(g2d, biggerRect, squareColor);` instead

Comment: It worked, thank you so much for you help. It is really appreciated!!